# CMS Made Simple .htaccess Redirect for non-WWW

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with a CMS Made Simple website that has pretty URLs enabled.

At the moment I have `http://www.example.com/` going to `http://example.com/`

However If I try and access `http://www.example.com/pagename` it goes to `http://example.com/index.php?page=pagename` when it should be going to `http://example.com/pagename`

Additionally I want to redirect `http://example.com/index.php` to `http://example.com/`

I've included the contents of my .htaccess file below:

```bash
# Attempt to override some php settings, these settings may be helpful on some hosts if your
# default configuration does not meet CMS's minimum requirements, and your host
# has given your account appropriate permissions
#php_value upload_max_filesize "10M"
#php_value session_save_path "tmp/cache"

#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
#php_flag register_globals Off
#php_flag session.use_trans_sid Off

# (this is important, so uncomment if your host permit)
#Options -Indexes
#ServerSignature Off

#Options +FollowSymLinks

# To prevent E_STRICT problems with PHP 5.3+ you can uncomment the following lines
# Note: These settings should only be enabled for production sites!
#php_flag display_startup_errors 0
#php_flag display_errors 0
#php_flag html_errors 0
#php_value docref_root 0
#php_value docref_ext 0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#
#Sub-dir e.g: /cmsms
RewriteBase /

# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
# but ignore POST requests.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST$
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_header.c>
# Disable ETags
Header unset ETag
FileEtag None
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress css, plaintext, xml, gif, and images in transport.
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/plain text/xml image/gif image/jpeg image/png
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
# Set expires tags on various files... so that the browser wont attempt to reload them.
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
<IfModule mod_header.c>
  # Setting cache control to public allowes proxy servers to cache the items too.
  Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the www to non-www redirect *above* the internal `index.php` rewrite. Additionally, I would recommend adding the `L` flag to the internal rewrite. This flag is required for the 'www' redirect as well. Lastly, the internal rewrite needs to use `(.*)` instead of `(.+)` as the former includes requests to the root, whilst the latter does not.

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Currently, the request is internally re-written to `index.php?page=$1`, which becomes the new request URI, which is then appended to the next redirect if 'www' is not included. Swapping those two blocks around will solve the issue.

To redirect `/index.php` to `/`, place the following redirect *above* the 'www' redirect shown above.

```bash
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=302,L]
```

To make that redirect permanent and cached by browsers and search engines, change 302 to 301.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've tried making the changes you've suggested, but it still doesn't seem to work...

The pages now do this: http://example.com/?page=pagename 

When trying to access the www version it does this: http://www.example.com/?page=http://example.com/&page=http://example.com/

Comment: Please try the updated code. Have a look at the [complete `.htaccess` file](http://hastebin.com/ufahajawix.apache) that works on my testing server.

Comment: Brilliant! That works! The only bit that doesn't work still is redirecting the index.php to the root when I add in this: RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=302,L]

Comment: Where did you add that? Works on my end.

Comment: I added it above the other rules, but when I do that the index.php does redirect to the root, but the other pages then do this: http://example.com/?page=pagename

Comment: I did test it on my server, and it wasn't doing that at all... Could be a caching issue on your side. Did you clear your cache? Alternatively, you can opn developer tools and, under settings, check the box that says you can disable the cache whilst dev tools is open.